# how to make a sharp graph smoother over a long period of time in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Example testdata

```
  testdata_1140.csv=structure(list(lead_create = structure(c(1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2018-05-13T01:48:07Z", "2018-05-15T22:56:10Z", 
    "2018-05-15T23:20:03Z", "2018-05-16T05:08:13Z", "2018-05-17T09:51:09Z", 
    "2018-05-17T15:49:02Z"), class = "factor"), lead_id = c(33238869L, 
    33417893L, 33427728L, 33359746L, 33238869L, 33360456L, 33371790L, 
    33238869L, 33360456L, 33360456L), approved_at = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), called_at = structure(c(2L, 10L, 
    9L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("2018-05-14T23:44:25Z", 
    "2018-05-15T01:56:42Z", "2018-05-15T23:22:32Z", "2018-05-16T00:36:37Z", 
    "2018-05-16T00:53:31Z", "2018-05-16T01:35:31Z", "2018-05-16T20:52:19Z", 
    "2018-05-17T03:51:26Z", "2018-05-17T20:41:04Z", "2018-05-18T02:16:42Z"
    ), class = "factor"), product = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Titan Gel", class = "factor"), 
        lead_country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L), .Label = "Taiwan", class = "factor"), class = c(0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("lead_create", 
    "lead_id", "approved_at", "called_at", "product", "lead_country", 
    "class"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I need create the plot for 1140 min. This dataset is part of large dataset and  was taken as test data.
So to select random data i do so. The main task is to get smooth long plot.
But after code working  I have a rough oscillator chart
like on this picture
[image]

How to do very long smooth plot on 1140 minutes?
Let it be on the entire monitor screen. 
where every decline is smooth, and for a minute.
Desired plot i try draw in mspaint (sorry i can't cool draw :-) )
[image]
So i want see in detail each curve.
Are there ways to make the chart as detailed as possible so that the downturn curves are visible.

```
# Get 10 random leads
set.seed(0)
indV<-sample(x = 1:nrow(dt),size = 10,replace = F)

# Write to file this subset
fwrite(file = "testdata_1140.csv",x = dt[indV,])

# Progress bar
pb <- progress_bar$new(
  format = "[:bar] :percent eta: :eta",
  total = length(indV), clear = FALSE, width= 60)

for(i in 1:length(indV)) {
  # Get main values for one lead id
  mainV<-dt[indV[i],]
  # Filtering data for current lead id
  s_dt<-dt %>% filter(product==mainV$product,lead_country==mainV$lead_country)
  s_dt$d<-s_dt$called_at-s_dt$lead_create
  s_dt<-s_dt %>% select(-c(lead_create, called_at))


  #head(s_dt)
  #cat("The dimension is:",dim(s_dt),"\n")

  # Create random forest model
  set.seed(0) # For reproducive results

  # Here we get indexies for 1 and 0 classes
  pos0<-which(s_dt$class==0)
  pos1<-which(s_dt$class==1)
  # Find the minimum number of classes
  min_l<-min(c(length(pos0),length(pos1)))
  # Restricted the large sizes of data sets
  if(min_l>5e+4) min_l<-5e+4

  # Resample data for balancing of classes
  pos0<-sample(x = pos0,size = min_l,replace = T)
  pos1<-sample(x = pos1,size = min_l,replace = T)
  # Get resampled data set
  s_dt2<-s_dt[c(pos0,pos1),]


  # create random forest
  m<-randomForest(x = data.table(d=as.numeric(s_dt2$d)),
                  y = as.factor(s_dt2$class),
                  ntree = 100,nodesize = 1)
  # Print the main results of this model
  #print(m)
  #pr2<-predict(object = m,newdata = data.table(d=as.numeric(s_dt2$d)))
  #cat("The accuracy of sampled data:",100*Accuracy(y_pred = s_dt2$CLASS,y_true = pr2),"%\n")
  # get aposterior probability 
  pr<-predict(object = m,newdata = data.table(d=as.numeric(s_dt$d)))
  real_ac<-100*Accuracy(y_pred = s_dt$class,y_true = pr)
  #cat("The accuracy of unsampled:",real_ac,"%\n")

  # Create the time steps (48 hours by 5 mins)
  difV<-seq(0,1140*60,60)
  # Predict each time steps
  prob_pos<-100*predict(object = m,newdata = data.table(d=difV),type = "prob")[,2]
  # Create required table:
  res<-data.table(lead_create=mainV$lead_create,
                  called_at=mainV$lead_create+difV,
                  prob=round(prob_pos,2),
                  prob_corrected=round(sqrt(prob_pos*real_ac),2))
  #res<-res %>% arrange(-PROB_APP)
  #head(res,8)

  # sorting by call date and time the results
  res<-res %>% arrange(res$called_at)

  # create and save plot
  png(filename = paste0("plot_1140_",i,".png"),
      width = 1024,height = 800)
  par(cex.main=0.8)
  # Correction
  res$prob_corrected<-((length(res$prob_corrected)-1):0)/(length(res$prob_corrected)-1)
  res$prob_corrected<-res$prob_corrected*runif(n = length(res$prob_corrected),min = 0.5,max = 0.7)
  plot(x = 0:(nrow(res)-1),
       y = res$prob_corrected,type="l", col="lightblue",
       xlab="Time of call",ylab="Probability of approval",
       main=paste0("lead_create: ",mainV$lead_create,"\n",
                   "lead_id: ",mainV$lead_id,"\n",
                   "country: ",mainV$lead_country,"\n",
                   "product: ",mainV$product,"\n",
                   "start time of calls: ",res$called_at[1],
                   collapse = ""),xaxt="n")
  #axis(1, xaxp=c(0, nrow(res)-1, nrow(res)-1), las=1)
  hs<-(minute(mainV$lead_create):(minute(mainV$lead_create)+1140))%%59
  hs[hs==0]<-59

  axis(1, at=1:nrow(res), labels=hs,cex.axis=0.7)

  indV2<-which(res$prob_corrected<=1e-3)
  indV2<-indV2[indV2>1]
  indV2<-indV2[1]
  abline(v = (0:(nrow(res)-1))[indV2],col="red")

  grid()

  dev.off()
  pb$tick()
}
```

Comment: I do not fully understand what you want. But if you want to be able to "zoom" and see all the details export your plot using `png` or `pdf` and put a very high resolution

Comment: You could use `cut` to separate the data and use `ggplot2::facet_wrap` on this new variable to get more plots.

Comment: Please read and edit your question according to [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that other users can help you